# Is there a way to not show the user the size and available space of a mapped Windows Fileshare?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, network-share

Is it possible to not show the user the disk size and available space on their mapped fileshares? I would like to not display "132GB free of 145GB" if possible.

Server 2012
Windows 7

Comment: While the provided solution does not hide the size, it does indeed show the users only what is available up to the cap, which works for me.

Comment: If you set the view to icon it hides the information. You could do that with group policy